# Spring boot Angular2, return PDF in JSON

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, filesaver.js

I have a Spring boot REST API which must return a PDF. I have converted the PDF to a byte array, then I encoded it in base64 before returning it to the client.

Here are my interface:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Update an existing form", notes = "Update an existing form ", response = Void.class, tags={  })
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "form response", response = Void.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "unexpected error", response = Void.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/forms/{formId}/submissions/{submissionId}/pdf",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<Resource> pdf(
            @ApiParam(value = "Id of the form that needs to be updated", required = true) @PathVariable("formId") Long formId,
            @ApiParam(value = "Id of the submission that needs to be updated", required = true) @PathVariable("submissionId") Long submissionId,
            @ApiParam(value = "token to be passed as a header", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "token", required = true) String token
    );
```

And the implemented method:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> pdf(@ApiParam(value = "Id of the form that needs to be updated", required = true) @PathVariable("formId") Long formId, @ApiParam(value = "Id of the submission that needs to be updated", required = true) @PathVariable("submissionId") Long submissionId, @ApiParam(value = "token to be passed as a header", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "token", required = true) String token) {
        String name = JWTutils.getEmailInToken(token);

        if(name == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(name);

        if(user == null){
            return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }

        Form form = formRepository.findById(formId);

        if(form == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        Submission submission = submissionRepository.findOne(submissionId);

        if(submission == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        //Saving the document
        final PDPage singlePage = new PDPage();
        final PDFont courierBoldFont = PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD;
        final int fontSize = 12;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (final PDDocument document = new PDDocument())
        {
            document.addPage(singlePage);
            final PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, singlePage);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(courierBoldFont, fontSize);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(150, 750);
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.showText("Hello PDFBox");
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();  // Stream must be closed before saving document.
            //document.save("pdfs/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".pdf");
            document.save(out);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] b64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(out.toByteArray());
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(b64);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentLength(b64.length)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(resource);
    }
```

And here is the code in Angular2:

```
generatePdf(){
    this.submissionService.generatePdf(this.form.id, this.submission.id).then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        let file = new Blob([atob(data._body)]);
        FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'helloworld.pdf')
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

The PDF i receive in the payload looks like this: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/ep7XtqQs)

When I open the downloaded PDF it contains only one page which is empty while the real pdf contains text. Any idea what's happening? I feel like it's about encoding.

---

**SOLUTION**

I had to change my GET request in my service. I've added this to my request `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob;`

```
return this.http.get(this.formsUrl + "/" + formId + "/submissions/" + submissionId + "/pdf", {headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I had to change my GET request in my service. I've added this to my request `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob;`

```
return this.http.get(this.formsUrl + "/" + formId + "/submissions/" + submissionId + "/pdf", {headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```